# Group by array elements on basis of certain criteria from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of 50 elements each having some record type. I need to filter elements of similar record type using jquery. How would I do that.

Please help

Comment: Can include example of array , _"record type"_ at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

To divide similar elements by a simple property you can use [Bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort):

```
//Elements to divide into buckets according to their foo value:
var elems = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 23}
, {foo: 2, bar: 24}
, {foo: 1, bar: 25}
, {foo: 2, bar: 26}
, {foo: 2, bar: 27}
, {foo: 3, bar: 29}
];
//Sorting elements into buckets depending on foo:
var buckets = {};
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
  var elem = elems[i];
  if(elem.foo in buckets){
    buckets[elem.foo].push(elem);
  }else{
    buckets[elem.foo] = [elem];
  }
}
//Iterating buckets to display output:
var keys = Object.keys(buckets);
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  var key = keys[i];
  console.log(key+' => '+JSON.stringify(buckets[key]));
}
```

This would produce the following output:

```
1 => [{"foo":1,"bar":23},{"foo":1,"bar":25}]
2 => [{"foo":2,"bar":24},{"foo":2,"bar":26},{"foo":2,"bar":27}]
3 => [{"foo":3,"bar":29}]
```